# Constraining class generic type to a Tuple

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, generics

1. I'd like do create a class with one generic TKey, where TKey is one of [System.Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) types that can be created.

   ```
   public class Class1<TKey> where TKey : System.Tuple
   { 
          /// Class Stuff Goes Here where TKey is one of the 8 tuple 
              types found in the link in (1)

   }
   ```

I am not so sure how to implement this.  The goal is to prevent myself from implementing a class for each tuple class.

Comment: Each different `Tuple<>` type has a different number of generic arguments, and they are therefore different types.  You can't add a constraint against all of them at once.  Is there a reason that `TKey` *needs* to be constrained?

Comment: @cdhowie I answered the question in your solution, but I'll post it here "there is absolute reason that it has to be one of the tuple classes, the idea is to have TKey to act as a key with n parameters, i.e. T1, T2, T3, ..., Tn."

Answer (score 21):

You can't as others have stated, but you can **almost** do it.

So all the `Tuple<...>` classes have a signature like this:

```
public class Tuple<T1, ...> : 
    IStructuralEquatable, 
    IStructuralComparable, 
    IComparable, 
    ITuple
```

All of those interfaces save `ITuple` are public (`ITuple` is an internal interface), so you can try crafting something like so:

```
public interface ITupleKey<TKey>
    where TKey : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable
{
}
```

"But wait!", you say, "How can I be sure nothing else is implementing those interfaces?"

Well, you can't. But like I said, this is just an *almost* way - luckily, `IStructuralEquatable` and `IStructuralComparable` are only (at the framework level, naturally) used in the following types:

```
System.Array
System.Tuple<T1>
System.Tuple<T1,T2>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRest>
```

So it's pretty close. Combine this with a runtime check that `TKey` actually is some variant of `Tuple`, and you might have what you need.

EDIT:

Some basic usage:

```
public class Class1<TKey> 
    where TKey : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable
{ 
}

// will compile
var classTup1 = new Class1<Tuple<int>>();
var classTup2 = new Class1<Tuple<int,int>>();
var classTup3 = new Class1<Tuple<int,int,int>>();
var classTup4 = new Class1<Tuple<int,int,int,int>>();
var classTup5 = new Class1<Tuple<int,int,int,int,int>>();

// won't compile
var badclassTup1 = new Class1<int>();
var badclassTup2 = new Class1<string>();
var badclassTup3 = new Class1<object>();
```

And, because I've clearly gone insane, let's see what's possible here:

```
public class Class1<TKey> 
    where TKey : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable
{ 
    public Class1(TKey key)
    {
        Key = key;
        TupleRank = typeof(TKey).GetGenericArguments().Count();
        TupleSubtypes = typeof(TKey).GetGenericArguments();
        Console.WriteLine("Key type is a Tuple (I think) with {0} elements", TupleRank);
        TupleGetters = 
            Enumerable.Range(1, TupleRank)
                .Select(i => typeof(TKey).GetProperty(string.Concat("Item",i.ToString())))
                .Select(pi => pi.GetGetMethod())
                .Select(getter => Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                            typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(getter.ReturnType), 
                            this.Key, 
                            getter))
                .ToList();
    }

    public int TupleRank {get; private set;}
    public IEnumerable<Type> TupleSubtypes {get; private set;}
    public IList<Delegate> TupleGetters {get; private set;}
    public TKey Key {get; private set;}

    public object this[int rank]
    {
        get { return TupleGetters[rank].DynamicInvoke(null);}
    }
    public void DoSomethingUseful()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<TupleRank; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key value for {0}:{1}", string.Concat("Item", i+1), this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Test rig:

```
var classTup1 = new Class1<Tuple<int>>(Tuple.Create(1));
var classTup2 = new Class1<Tuple<int,int>>(Tuple.Create(1,2));
var classTup3 = new Class1<Tuple<int,int,int>>(Tuple.Create(1,2,3));
var classTup4 = new Class1<Tuple<int,int,int,int>>(Tuple.Create(1,2,3,4));
var classTup5 = new Class1<Tuple<int,int,int,int,int>>(Tuple.Create(1,2,3,4,5));

classTup1.DoSomethingUseful();
classTup2.DoSomethingUseful();
classTup3.DoSomethingUseful();
classTup4.DoSomethingUseful();
classTup5.DoSomethingUseful();
```

Output:

```
Key type is a Tuple (I think) with 1 elements
Key type is a Tuple (I think) with 2 elements
Key type is a Tuple (I think) with 3 elements
Key type is a Tuple (I think) with 4 elements
Key type is a Tuple (I think) with 5 elements
Key value for Item1:1
Key value for Item1:1
Key value for Item2:2
Key value for Item1:1
Key value for Item2:2
Key value for Item3:3
Key value for Item1:1
Key value for Item2:2
Key value for Item3:3
Key value for Item4:4
Key value for Item1:1
Key value for Item2:2
Key value for Item3:3
Key value for Item4:4
Key value for Item5:5
```

Comment: Thanks for this post.  I might consider it for implementation.

Comment: @MaelstromYamato Good Luck! I added a quick-and-dirty usage example as well

Comment: In my experience this is the next best solution right behind not creating this problem in the first place. It gives you access to all the members of those interfaces which are common.

Comment: Agreed; I just like trying to figure out ways one can abuse the type system. ;)

Comment: After working to demo your solution, it can be done but is a very ugly implementation. :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised no one suggested that you constrain your class (or in my case a method) based on the `ITuple` interface. To illustrate your example:

```
public class Class1<T> where T : ITuple
```

You need to reference the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` assembly.

My particular use case is one where I wanted to iterate though a collection of tuples of unknown shape. My solution was along the lines of:

```
public static void ProcessTupleCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) where T: ITuple
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var fields = type.GetFields();
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            field.GetValue(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is an old one but I hope this helps those who might stumble upon it :)

Comment: I'm surprised you are using reflection for accesing your `ITuple` values instead of using indexes since `ITuple` has a Length property along with and `Int32[Int32]` index property... +1 though but you should add that info for completeness sake. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this, for two reasons.

First, you can't do "or" constraints on generic types.  You could have to have a constraint on `Tuple<T1, T2>` *or* `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`.  This is not possible.

Second, you would need to "pass through" generic arguments, like so:

```
public class Class1<TKey, T1, T2> where TKey : System.Tuple<T1, T2>
```

So, you would need a variable number of generic type arguments for your class, and this is not supported either.

Unless there is a specific reason why `TKey` *absolutely has to be* one of the tuple classes, leave it unconstrained.

Comment: there is absolute reason that it has to be one of the tuple classes, the idea is to have TKey to act as a key with n parameters, i.e. T1, T2, T3, ..., Tn.

Comment: @MaelstromYamato But *why* does it have to be one of the tuple classes? Do you intend to cast the result to a specific Tuple type? Why could someone not implement their own tuple-like class and then use that?

Comment: To clarify: since you can't determine *which* tuple type is in use here, you couldn't cast it to a specific `Tuple<>` type with any confidence, even if you could (ab)use generics this way.

Comment: TKey is based on a set of parameters, i.e. T1, T2, ..., Tn.  I have several situations where the total number of parameters are different.  So is Tuple necessary?  I would say no. however, for any n, T1, T2, ..., Tn, can be thought of as a tuple, hence I think a constraint on TKey is reasonable.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to go about this if the number of TKey parameters can vary?

Comment: Any number of T's can be thought of as a tuple, but the framework only has Tuple types for up to eight T's.

No, there isn't even a way to specify a variable number of generic arguments in this way.

Comment: thans for the information,  I will consider alternatives for my implementation.

Comment: @cdhowie just nitpicking, but the eighth "T" is itself a Tuple in cases > 8, if I recall correctly

Comment: @JerKimball It can be, but honestly if you're nesting Tuple instances like that then you probably should be using a proper POD type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The different generic variants of Tuple does not have a reasonable common base class or interface.

The purpose of generic constraint is to tell the compiler what members the generic type is expected to have.

Answer (score -1):

Like so:

```
public class Class1<TKey,P,Q> where TKey : System.Tuple<P,Q>
{ 
       /// Class Stuff Goes Here where TKey is one of the 8 tuple 
           types found in the link in (1)

}
```

Add the generic parameters of Tuple to your class'

As per the comment below, there's no way to combine this into one class without interfaces or reflection. If there was there wouldn't have been multiple Tuple classes

But... you can define your own base interface that's inherited by multiple Class1 and then use that interface as a constraint. Doesn't sound pretty but would work

Comment: This will not allow `TKey` to be any of the other tuple types, such as `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`.  This is required by the OP's question.